Error migrating files with Cyrillic when using Docker for Mysql. Docker doesn't read Mysql config. Windows OS
I have Windows OS. When I try to migrate in Docker I get an error
(details: Error 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x9C\xD0\xBE\xD0\xB4...' for column 'name' at row 1)
app      | make: *** [Makefile:30: migrate.up] Error 1

And in the Docker logs it also says
mysqld: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored.

My docker-compose file:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:alpine
    platform: linux/amd64
    restart: "on-failure"
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    env_file: .env
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 5s
    volumes:
      - ./db/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf:ro

My config:
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
init_connect ='SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_general_ci'
init_connect ='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

The problem with migration only goes away if you directly set the encoding type in docker-compose.
command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
But at the same time, broken characters are displayed in the CMD or PowerShell due to the Cyrillic alphabet.
All UTF-8 and Line-Sepator files are configured as LF.

Note, MariaDB changed it server code so read only mounts of configuration files like you have actually works. You might have to make the file read only in Windows to make this work with MySQL. Side note, there are better collations in MySQL (UCA 9.0.0) and MariaDB (14.0.0) that will order urf8mb4. MariaDB 11.4+ containers use it by default.
